# Solved Mysql connection lost with HAProxy

Tags: mysql, load-balancing

I have master-master replication with mysql. and haproxy configured front of my master-master replication. 
When I connect my replication via HaProxy, mysql says that "MYSQL has gone away". But when I connect my replication via mysql1 or mysql2 servers no problem.

is there any haProxy config about mysql connection time out ?
**UPDATE**
I finally solved. 
Problem is HaProxy config file's server and timeout values. You can increase this values according to your system and architecture.