# Haproxy + Mysql Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, haproxy

I have setup a master-slave replication and added a haproxy before them.

```
#HA-Proxy version 1.4.24

global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend ft_readonly_mysql
    mode tcp
    timeout client 50000
    option clitcpka
    bind *:3308
    default_backend bk_readonly_mysql

backend bk_readonly_mysql
    mode tcp
    option srvtcpka
    timeout server 50000
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    server mysql1 127.0.0.1:3306 check
    server mysql2 172.16.19.250:3306 check
```

If my `pymysql` client connect to mysql via 3306 directly, it works well. If connect to mysql via haproxy 3308 port, it will throw `OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')` every several minutes.

I doubted it was due to haproxy config so that I have added `clitcpka`, `srvtcpka`, `timeout client`, `timeout server`. But it still throws `Lost connection`.

Update 0:

```
mysql> show global variables like '%timeout%';
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout            | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout          | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30       |
| net_write_timeout          | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
| wait_timeout               | 28800    |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: seems like connection time out is not appropriate..look for show variables like '%timeout%'; to see what time out values you have set. Moreover after how much time it gives error?

Comment: see update 0. The first time I saw this error costed 5 mins.

Comment: I'm running into this issue currently. Seems like this is indeed a configuration issue on the HAProxy side per this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61793/35702. Did you every solve your issue?

Comment: Threads https://stackoverflow.com/a/37426548/399435 and https://serverfault.com/a/730565/140709 also confirm that the `timeout server` and `timeout client` parameters need to tweaked on HAProxy to resolve this issue. I'm going to give this a shot and hopefully it'll resolve my issues.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Keep the timeouts in HAProxy and MySQL / MariaDB the same.

I've run into this issue on and off when I fire some long running quries. I'm posting the relevant section from an [article](https://severalnines.com/resources/whitepapers/mysql-load-balancing-with-haproxy/) here that has worked well for me:

> **MySQL Server has gone away**
>
> This is usually caused when HAProxy has closed the connection due to
> timeout or the connection is closed on the server side. Sometimes, you
> could see this when the server is restarting or the connection has
> reached one of the following timeouts.
>
> Our recommendation is to configure the @net_read_timeout@ and
> @net_write_timeout@ value in MySQL / MariaDB with the same value as
> for @timeout client@ and @timeout server@ in HAProxy configuration
> file.

Based on the above, your configuration should look like this for HAProxy:

```
# haproxy.cfg

...

defaults
        timeout client  3600
        timeout server  3600
...
```

You can also add the timeouts to a specific frontend or backend configuration in the HAProxy config

And like this for MySQL / MariaDB:

```
# my.cnf

[mysqld]
...
net_read_timeout = 3600
net_write_timeout = 3600
...
```

Here is an excerpt from [another article](https://support.severalnines.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360054693112-HAPROXY-timeout-client-timeout-server-and-Mysql-net-read-timeout-net-write-timeout-) questioning the same recommendation:

> Please keep in mind that there's no magic number which is the best
> setting for given variable. In one case longer timeouts may work
> better, in other case you would prefer shorter ones. This is up to you
> to decide what is the best setting for your environment, application
> and workload. It doesn't have to me 10800 seconds. It may be 30, 60,
> 3600 or anything else.